# Почему nginx проксирует неправильно?

Tags: linux, apache, nginx, debian

Не уверен, что это вопрос, подходящий для stackoverflow...

Делал веб сервер на linux debian 8 (jessie)
со следующей системой

(пользователь подключится по host1) -> (apache открыл сайт, связанный с host1)
(пользователь подключится по host2) -> (apache открыл сайт, связанный с host2)

Далее, для увеличения производительности сервера я решил проксировать все это дело с помощью nginx по статье
ссылка: https://softnastroy.com/content/ustanovka-nginx-dlya-ispconfig-3-na-server-debian.html#comment-629

И у меня все получилось (если бы), кроме одного - при перенаправлении запросов nginx'ом

nginx: proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;

apache перестаёт понимать по какому хосту подключался пользователь и открывает стандартный сайт /var/www/ ... /index.php

При обработке статичных запросов nginx работает нормально, также при подключении напрямую к apache (по другому порту [82]) тоже отображение идет нормально.

Если проксировать с выходом в интернет

nginx: proxy_pass [http://ip_машины-сервера:82](http://ip_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0:82);

то тоже все работает как часы.

Вопрос: как настроить nginx и apache, чтобы при подключении с разных доменов apache, "спрятавшийся за nginx", понимал какой именно сайт ему надо отобразить.

(в дальнейшем порт apache планируется закрыть от "внешнего" подключения из соображений безопасности, поэтому проксирование должно вестись локально)

Имеется мысль что как-то должен помочь "proxy_set_header Host $host;", но пока с ним все безуспешно.

Config nginx:

```
server {
    listen  80 default;
    server_name  _;
    server_name_in_redirect  off;
    resolver  127.0.0.1;
    error_page 404 = @fallback;

# send all errors to Apache 2
location @fallback {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    }

# setting nginx handler for static content
location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|swf|flv|mp3)$ {
    root /var/www/$host/web;
    access_log off;
    expires 30d;
    }

# other content
location / { 

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:82;

    }
}
```

Comment: покажи конфигурацию nginx

Comment: Добавил конфиг.
Я решил проблему, используя стандартную /html директорию. 
У меня 1 сайт и этого хватает. Хотя вообще это не гуд, конечно...